# How to get the last line of a binary file in C?

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io

I want to get the last record in a binary file, extract its ID and add one to it to mimic an auto-incrementing ID feature. So for example, if the previous user had an ID of 1, then the next user should have an ID of 2, and so on. The issue is I can't get the last record of the binary file using the code below. How can I go about doing this? Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Applicant
{
    int id;
};

void increment()
{
    char fileName = "data.dat";

    FILE *file;

    // Instantiate the applicant struct
    struct Applicant applicant;

    // Will contain details of the last applicant in the file
    struct Applicant previousApplicant;

    // Open the file in 'append binary' mode
    file = fopen(fileName, "ab");

    // If file does not exist, print error message and exit
    if (!file) 
    {
        printf("\nSorry, that file does not exist");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read the last applicant to get their id
    while(1)
    {

        fread(&previousApplicant, sizeof(previousApplicant), 1, file);

        if (feof(file)) { break; }

    }

    // If there's no previous applicant, set the ID to 100
    if (previousApplicant.id == 0)
    {
        applicant.id = 100;
    }

    // Otherwise just increment the previous applicant's id and assign it to the new applicant
    else
    {
        applicant.id = previousApplicant.id + 1;
    }

    fwrite(&applicant, sizeof(applicant), 1, file);

    fclose(file);

}
```

To achieve this, I'm using structs

Comment: "having trouble" is not very descriptive. Please describe in detail what the actual error or incorrect behaviour is.

Comment: The file pointer is already at the end of the file after the `fread` loop. Need to reposition with `fseek` to the right position for the `fwrite`. Also, add proper error checking to make your code more robust and to aid debugging - check all function return values for errors.

Comment: Another thing - an optimisation is to remove the `fread` loop and just  jump straight to the last record by using `fseek` with `SEEK_END` and a negative offset.

Comment: If this is a binary file, how does it have "lines"?

Comment: *"The issue is I can't get the last record of the binary file"* -- well, I have the same issue with the code `int main() { return 0; }`. Perhaps you could be a bit more descriptive and detailed about what fails? (What symptoms did you observe?) Maybe describe why you thought it would work?

Comment: What exactly is a "line" in a binary file?

Comment: @kaylum I'm not sure if `SEEK_END` on a binary file is portable since [Binary streams are not required to support SEEK_END](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek#:~:text=Binary%20streams%20are%20not%20required%20to%20support%20SEEK_END)

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd suggest doing it is to call [fseek()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to seek directly to the last record in the file, read it in to RAM, update it, and write it out again.  That way you don't have to read in every record in the file just to update the last one, which would be really inefficient if the file is large and/or you have to perform this operation often.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Applicant
{
    int id;
};

void increment()
{
    const char fileName[] = "data.dat";

    // Open the file in 'append binary' mode
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "a+b");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't open file [%s]\n", fileName);
       return;
    }

    // Seek to the end of the file
    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
    {
       printf("Couldn't seek to the end of the file!\n");
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // Will contain details of the last applicant in the file
    struct Applicant previousApplicant;

    // Check to make sure the file is big enough to hold at least one record
    const long fileLengthBytes = ftell(file);
    if (fileLengthBytes < sizeof(previousApplicant))
    {
       printf("File is to short to contain a full record!?\n");
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // Check to make sure the file length is an even multiple of the record-length
    if ((fileLengthBytes % sizeof(previousApplicant)) != 0)
    {
       printf("File length (%li) is not a multiple of record size (%zu)!?\n", fileLengthBytes, sizeof(previousApplicant));
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // Seek backwards to the start of the last record in the file
    if (fseek(file, -sizeof(previousApplicant), SEEK_CUR) != 0)
    {
       printf("Couldn't seek to the start of the last record in the file!\n");
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // Read in the last record in the file
    if (fread(&previousApplicant, sizeof(previousApplicant), 1, file) != 1)
    {
       printf("Couldn't read the last record in the file!\n");
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // Increment the record
    printf("Incrementing ID of last record in the file from %i to %i\n", previousApplicant.id, previousApplicant.id+1);
    previousApplicant.id++;

    // Finally, write out the new record in the file with incremented ID
    if (fwrite(&previousApplicant, sizeof(previousApplicant), 1, file) != 1)
    {
       printf("Couldn't write the last record in the file!\n");
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }

    // success!
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    increment();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with your code. You were reading the applicant ID into the `applicant` struct variable rather than the `previousApplicant` variable and when reading and writing files it is best to separate out the tasks: first open the file for reading, then when you're ready to write, close it and open it for writing.

Here's the modified working code which will do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Applicant
{
    int id;
};

void increment()
{
    char* fileName = "data.dat";

    FILE *file;

    // Instantiate the applicant struct
    struct Applicant applicant;

    // Will contain details of the last applicant in the file
    struct Applicant previousApplicant;

    // Open the file in 'append binary' mode
    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    // If file does not exist, print error message and exit
    if (!file) 
    {
        printf("\nSorry, that file does not exist");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read the last applicant to get their id
    while(1)
    {

        fread(&previousApplicant, sizeof(applicant), 1, file);
        if( feof(file) ) break;
        
    }

    // If there's no previous applicant, set the ID to 100
    if (previousApplicant.id == 0)
    {
        applicant.id = 100;
    }

    // Otherwise just increment the previous applicant's id and assign it to the new applicant
    else
    {
        applicant.id = previousApplicant.id + 1;
    }

    fclose(file);
    FILE* out = fopen(fileName, "ab");
    fwrite(&applicant, sizeof(applicant), 1, out);
    printf("%d\n", applicant.id);
    fclose(out);

}

void main()  {
    increment();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got the logic of what you are trying to do. As pointed above, you can use just `fseek()` to move the current pointer for the file.

from the [documentation][1]

```
int fseek(
   FILE *stream,
   long offset,
   int origin
);
int _fseeki64(
   FILE *stream,
   __int64 offset,
   int origin
);
```

**As for the offset:** you can use this pre-defined constants: `SEEK_CUR` meaning the current position in file, `SEEK_SET` meaning the beginning and `SEEK_END` pointing, well, to the END of the file. The current offset from the beginning of file you can get by calling `fseek()`'s sister, `ftell()`, that returns a `long` with the position. First byte is 0. You can for sure seek for any position.

**An example:**

At first consider this code:

```
int create(const char* f_name, unsigned int n_rec)
{
    Applicant one = {100};
    FILE*     f   = fopen(f_name, "wb");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n_rec; i += 1, one.id+= 1)
        if (fwrite(&one, sizeof(one), 1, f) != 1)
            return 1 + i;
    fclose(f);
    return n_rec;
};  // create()
```

This function creates the file and writes down the supplied number of IDs. e.g.

```
create( "x.dat", 300 )
```

will go as expected and create `x.dat` and write 300 IDs starting at 100 --- inclusive --- in the file.

Then the following function in the example below reopens the file, get the last ID used and returns it, and you can use it as a prototype:

```
int get_last_id(const char* f_name)
{
    Applicant one = {0};
    int       res = 0;
    FILE*     f   = fopen(f_name, "rb+");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    res = fseek(f, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);
    if (res != 0) return -2;
    res = fseek(f, -(long) (sizeof(one)), SEEK_END);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
        perror("Error in seek()");
        return -3;
    }
    printf("(file position: byte #%ld)\n", ftell(f));
    if (fread(&one, sizeof(one), 1, f) != 1) return -4;
    fclose(f);
    return one.id;
}
```

The lines you want are these:

```
    Applicant one = {0};
    fseek(f, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(f, -(long) (sizeof(one)), SEEK_END);
    fread(&one, sizeof(one), 1, f);
```

You go to the end if file, then goes back 1 record and read it.

#### sample output

```
5 Ids written to "sample.dat"
now open file and get the last ID used
(file position: byte #16)
Last ID on "sample.dat" is  104
```

For this

#### C code

````
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{   int id;

}   Applicant;

int  create(const char*,unsigned);
int  get_last_id(const char*);


int  main(void)
{
    const char*    f_name  = "sample.dat";
    const unsigned initial_size = 5;
    int            res     = 0;

    // a few ids are written to file
    if ( (res = create(f_name, initial_size)) < 0) return -1;
    printf("\
%d Ids written to \"%s\"\n\
now open file and get the last ID used\n",
        res, f_name);

    // get the last id on file
    res = get_last_id(f_name);

    if (res < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not get id from file (%d)\n", res);
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("Last ID on \"%s\" is % d\n", f_name,  res);

    return 0;
}


int get_last_id(const char* f_name)
{
    Applicant one = {0};
    int       res = 0;
    FILE*     f   = fopen(f_name, "rb+");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    res = fseek(f, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);
    if (res != 0) return -2;
    res = fseek(f, -(long) (sizeof(one)), SEEK_END);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
        perror("Error in seek()");
        return -3;
    }
    printf("(file position: byte #%ld)\n", ftell(f));
    if (fread(&one, sizeof(one), 1, f) != 1) return -4;
    fclose(f);
    return one.id;
}


int create(const char* f_name, unsigned int n_rec)
{
    Applicant one = {100};
    FILE*     f   = fopen(f_name, "wb");
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n_rec; i += 1, one.id+= 1)
        if (fwrite(&one, sizeof(one), 1, f) != 1)
            return 1 + i;
    fclose(f);
    return n_rec;
};  // create()
```

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-160
````